# How to transform date in r?

Tags: r, date

I have dataset with column Date such

```
1-Apr-08
18-Sep-09
```

And I want to transform them to

```
01/04/08
18/09/09
```

I try 
`format(as.Date(d, "%d-%b-%y"), "%d/%m/%y")`
but it doesn't work

UPD I found that my code doesn't work because system language of my PC is russian. When I try to transform 1-Апр-08, it works (Апрель = April).

Comment: As you found the answer you should either delete your question or put your update as answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code was correct. It didn't work because system language of my PC was russian. For example, When I tried to transform 1-Апр-08, it worked    routinely (Апрель is April in russian)

Answer (score 2):

When your `d` is a character, you can use:

```
format(as.Date(d, "%d-%b-%y"), "%d/%m/%y")
```

If not, then use

```
format(as.Date(as.character(d), "%d-%b-%y"), "%d/%m/%y")
```